# PayPal recurring subscriptions with credit card payments

Tags: paypal, subscription, recurring-billing

In my website I have integrated PayPal subscription. There client redirects to paypal site and do the payments and return to my site, it is fine. But my client wants to accept credit card payments, in current implementation users need to create paypal account in order to do credit card payments. As per my finding on the web we can do recurring credit card payments in following ways.

1. Collect credit card detail and store on paypal side and perform transaction when we need using a token. But this method supports only in UK and US
   https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/#direct-credit-card-payments
2. Collect credit card details and create recurring payment profiles via API. But this method possible only in US,UK,Canada only
3. We can do credit cards payments on PayPal site(without paypal account) with their Enhanced Recurring Payment service. It is not free($19.99/month)

My client is in France, So in my case only possible option is 3. Am I correct? Is there any other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, none of the option is available for France Merchants to process direct credit card payments.
The option 3 Enhanced Recurring Payment([ERP](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_product-go&product=premium_services)) is available for US,UK,AU and CA.

No, for France Merchants there is no way to accept direct credit card payments, only way is you can turn on "account optional" feature in paypal account and increase chances that buyer could pay with credit card along with PayPal with Website Payment standard or Express checkout

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any other way of doing it? I mean do credit cards payments without creating PayPal account? Even via a premium PayPal account. I`m confused with their documentation.